# AttributeError: module 'playwright' has no attribute 'chromium'

Tags: playwright-python

playwright install code

```
pip install playwright 
playwright install
```

import code

```
from playwright.sync_api import playwright,sync_playwright
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
```

But,keep prompting "AttributeError: module 'playwright' has no attribute 'chromium'",What is the reason, please?

```
AttributeError: module 'playwright' has no attribute 'chromium'
```

I tried asking ChatGPT, and the responses I got were as follows:

1.The playwright module may not have been installed correctly. You could create a new virtual environment and reinstall the playwright module in it to see if that solves the problem.
2.The playwright module you imported might not be the one you expected. In Python, if there are multiple modules with the same name, Python will import the first one it finds. You could check your Python environment to see if there are other modules named playwright.
3.The version of playwright you're using might be too old. In early versions of playwright, the chromium attribute might not have been available. You could try updating your playwright module to the latest version. Despite following these suggestions, I still couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What version of playwright-python do you have installed?

Comment: Make sure your pip and python are actually working together. Sometimes there are multiple versions of python on a system and the `pip install` refers to a different version of python that you're running when you `import` a module.

Comment: playwright-versrion (1.37.0),python-version (3.8)

Comment: I'm certain that pip and python can work together, and there are no issues with other libraries

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: Due to the project requirements, I am writing a web scraping program and plan to use Playwright to simulate browser operations.

Answer (score 0):

You want this I think:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()
page.goto('https://google.com/')
```

Or in other way (Much simpler in my opinion)

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto('https://google.com/')
```